# re-generate google-services.json to use gcm

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-signin, google-play-services

I am developing an app which use the google sign-in ,in order to that I have a google-services.json file ,now I need to use the Google Cloud Messaging service and my question is ,I need to generate another google-services.json file or can I use the google-services.json file I already have?

Answer (score 0):

Go here to create your google-services.json file:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

(you probably need to be logged in). From there, you can select the platform and then you can select the google services you want. Among them, there is google sign in and GCM. Select those two and generate your one google-services.json file.

I am not sure how you generated your current google-services.json file or what you did, so I am not sure if you should just replace it but I do know the above method is how you can create one google-services.json file to rule them all.